# What is Equal SQL Function or StoredProcedure for my C# Method

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have this C# Method that Determine that a point is inside a polygon or not

C# Method is this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determine that a point in inside a polygon or not
/// </summary>
/// <param name="points">Points of Polygon</param>
/// <param name="point">Test Point</param>
/// <returns></returns>    
Public bool IsInside(List<PointF> points,PointF point )
    {
        int i, j,n=points.Count;
        bool c = false;
        for (i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; j = i++)
        {
            if (((points[i].Y > point.Y) != (points[j].Y > point.Y)) &&
                (point.X <
                 (points[j].X - points[i].X)*(point.Y - points[i].Y)/(points[j].Y - points[i].Y) + points[i].X))
                c = !c;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

How can i convert this to a SQL Function or StoredProcedure?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name Microsoft SQL SERVER 2016

Comment: create two geometry instances and use [`STContains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933904.aspx)

Comment: An idea: you can pass the list of points as xml data and point as x and y parameters to your function or stored procedure. Inside the stored procedure or function load xml data into table using openxml (in function you would need table variable). Then run select query and put your condition of if block in where clause.

Comment: @MartinSmith can you write code of it for me? tnx

Comment: Where is your data held?  Are you using `Geography` or `Geometry` data types?

Comment: @iamdave none of them,i hold two field as Lat & Lng as float

Comment: So where is the polygon you are comparing your point to?  Also, if you look at my answer below, you will see how you can convert a latitude and longitude to a spatial point using the `geometry::STGeomFromText` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have all your polygons stored in your SQL Server database as spatial `geometry` data types, you can use the spatial functions available in SQL Server 2008R2+ of which there are many (Google is your friend here):

```
declare @g geometry
set @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-33.229869 -70.891988
                                           ,-33.251124 -70.476616
                                           ,-33.703094 -70.508045
                                           ,-33.693931 -70.891052
                                           ,-33.229869 -70.891988
                                           ))'
                                 ,0)

DECLARE @h geometry;

SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-33.3906300 -70.5725020)', 0);
SELECT @g.STContains(@h);
```